# segmentation fault while av_read_frame()

Tags: c, ffmpeg, segmentation-fault, libav, libavcodec

I have a media file and allocated the input to a contexts struct

```
typedef struct _contexts_{
    AVFormatContext *format_ctx;
    AVCodecContext  *audio_codec_ctx;
    AVCodec         *audio_codec;
    int     audio_stream_index;
}contexts;
```

I am sending an input file which contains 1 video and 3 audio streams in it. I have to do some operations on audio streams only. I tried to do copy the streams and allocate a new contexts struct. I read the input file and moved the value nb_streams to audio_streams. Below is the logic for copying I tried.

```
/*Reading input file 
..........
..........
*/
    contexts mctx[audio_streams];
    AVCodecParameters *param;
    AVStream *stream;
    AVCodecContext *avctx[audio_streams];
    for(i=0; i<audio_streams; i++){
            param = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
            mctx[i].audio_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_AC3);
            mctx[i].format_ctx = (AVFormatContext *)avformat_alloc_context();
            mctx[i].audio_codec_ctx  = (AVCodecContext *)avcodec_alloc_context3(mctx[i].audio_codec);
            stream = avformat_new_stream(mctx[i].format_ctx,mctx[i].audio_codec_ctx->codec);
            avcodec_parameters_from_context(param,stream->codec);
            avcodec_parameters_to_context(mctx[i].audio_codec_ctx,param);
            mctx[i].format_ctx->streams[0] = context_data.format_ctx->streams[i+1];
            avcodec_parameters_free(&param);
            mctx[i].audio_stream_index = i;
    }
```

Later I did the following

```
AVPacket packet;
av_init_packet(&packet);
int pkt_index = 0;

for(i=0; i < audio_streams;i++)
while((av_read_frame(mctx[i].format_ctx, &packet) >= 0)){
.........
```

I am getting the segmentation fault exactly at this av_read_frame(), it is exiting at this point. My questions are

1. Have I done the copying properly? If yes, why I am getting the error,
   If NO,
2. How to do and allocate the streams seperately to the contexts struct?

Any advice or suggestions would be helpful, Thank you.